# Xamarin.forms iOS label rendering issue inside collection view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i am using text binding of label inside a collection view and text type is Html,but Html couldn't be rendered successfully .. colors inside Html as example don't appear. any solution or workaround for this ?
Note : In android, works fine. this issue in iOS

Comment: i found this but still didn't try, it may be helpful to anyone face same issue https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin

Comment: Hi, I have tested in my local site, and it works in iOS and Android. The version of Xamarin Forms is `4.8.0.1560` , the iOS device is `14.1`. You could share the related code, I will check that.